# Working with View-related For Loops in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

These two pieces of oft-said MVC advice seem to be at odds with each other:

1. No for loops or conditional logic in the view
2. No HTML anywhere but the view

Let's say I have $items that have to be output as an unordered list. Isn't the iteration logic bound to have html in it? In which case, where should I put it?

It seems to me that reusability argues for putting it somewhere other than the view while providing the template author with parameters for the tag, class(es) etc.

What do you think? Practical reasons for why you think so are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can put loops in the view - how else are you going to render `<ul>`s? :))

You can put *a little* conditional logic too, e.g. printing "Logout" vs. "Login" in the upper right based on authorization status, mainly in shared portions of template.

The whole point is that the view layer has to be totally agnostic to the data it renders: he's a demiurge between a bunch of arrays / objects and the actual HTML rendered in the browser.
It's a **controller** matter to provide such data, i.e. to make all the decisions, the filtering stuff, and so.

Think about webservices: you may render the *same* resource in different formats [xml, json, plain html] - it's the controller that fetches the data from wherever, then the view takes it and renders a proper document.

Comment: "Of course you can put loops in the view" Yeah, I always thought so too, but I have seen people saying otherwise on here. It does seem to create a lot of redundant code spread across views.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always end up with some sort of loop when dealing with lists and tables on your **view templates**. The reason you hear people arguing that's a bad idea adding view logic in the template is related to the **ViewModel paradigm**.

Sometimes it's not enough to just loop through the data, for example:

```
<?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
    <?php if ( in_array( $user->getId(), $members ) ): ?>
    <!-- Users is member -->
```

In this specific case, the `user entity` doesn't have a method `isMember()` to check whether the user is a member or not. Assuming that you're using a 3rd party module that ships with the user entity and you don't want to extend this to add new dependencies (e.g. the groups). You must check this **outside of your domain model** in order to properly display the view template as in the example above.

But, in this case, we are **adding logic to the view**: `if ( in_array( $user->getId(), $members ) )`. You either should put it within your **business logic** or within your **view logic**. The later one is achieved using **ViewModels**. So instead of having your views interacting with domain model objects, it will **interact with a ViewModel**, which will implement the `isMember()` method and encapsulate the logic described above.

The main idea on this paradigm is that your view doesn't have access to the domain model, instead it interacts only with the ViewModels, **keeping views independent of the domain model.**

**UPDATE**

For example, if you have design/front-end team you would not allow them to call `$user->setName()` but just `$user->getName()` with a **ViewModel** you'll not include this method as an option.

There's another example: Let's say your application have skins/themes. If you keep the view logic, as in the first example on your view templates, you'll need to **duplicate** this logic for all themes with a similar template. Having this decoupled of your templates, you'll avoid duplicated view logic spread across your view templates.

Comment: ViewModels seems to put us in the realm of pure nomenclature. ViewModels are, what, a collection of functions for minor logic tasks associated with Views? How, in a practical, as opposed to doctrinal way, does this improve upon just stuffing the logic in the template?

Comment: I would like to see someone take really common web app use cases and describe what piece is handled where, optimally.

Comment: @MikeGirard Let me know if the updated answer solves your question